# Google signin. ERROR: statusCode = DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution = null

Tags: android, google-signin

We have several computer with different programmers developing the same project that involves a login using google, the code was made following the tutorial of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating.

The project was configured, and the sha1 keys of all the computers were registered but when trying to compile and run the application it only works from one of the computers.

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {

    try {

        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        _loginViewModel.LoginGoogle(account);

    } catch (ApiException e) {

        e.printStackTrace(); 

    }

}
```

When running the application in debug mode, after giving the google sign in button and selecting the account from which to obtain information, I get the error> `Status {statusCode = DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution = null}`